# Circumflex in format of lists

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

This works:

```lisp
(format nil "~{~a~^,~}" '(1 2 3))  ; => "1,2,3"
(format nil "~{~a=~a~^,~}" '(a 1 b 2 c 3)) ; => "A=1,B=2,C=3"
```

But in this example the circumflex suppresses everything:

```lisp
(format nil "~:{~a=~a~^,~}" '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))) ; => "A=1B=2C=3"
```

Why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to nest iterations so that the inner iteration works over the parameters and the outer iteration works over the lists of parameters. Then the outer iteration can be escaped to suppress printing the final comma:

```
* (format nil "~{~{~A=~A~}~^, ~}" '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3)))
"A=1, B=2, C=3"
```

Comment: I think the inner curly brackets have a different meaning than the outer. The inner brackets use the argument list for a a sequence of format instructions. But the outer brackets use the argument list in order to loop a format expression. How to know when the curly brackets have either the meaning of a sequence or the meaning of a loop?

Comment: @ceving -- they have the same meaning. The outer braces takes the lists `(a 1)`, `(b 2)`, and `(c 3)` in turn as arguments and applies them to the control string `~{~A=~A~}~^,`. The braces of this control string takes each of the elements `a` and `1` from the first list in sequence and applies them to the inner control string `~A=~A`, and so on for the other list arguments.